# Next Js does not deploy for SaSS. SassError: Can't find stylesheet to import

Tags: sass, deployment, next.js, vercel

I have a problem with `Sass Error`. I made a project on a `Next Js` and when deploying `Vercel` the console return this error.

```
Failed to compile.
./styles/app.scss.webpack[javascript/auto]!=!./node_modules/next/dist/build/webpack/loaders/css-loader/src/index.js??ruleSet[1].rules[3].oneOf[9].use[1]!./node_modules/next/dist/build/webpack/loaders/postcss-loader/src/index.js??ruleSet[1].rules[3].oneOf[9].use[2]!./node_modules/next/dist/build/webpack/loaders/resolve-url-loader/index.js??ruleSet[1].rules[3].oneOf[9].use[3]!./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/sass-loader/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[3].oneOf[9].use[4]!./styles/app.scss
SassError: Can't find stylesheet to import.
   ╷
14 │ @import "pages/Haveproject.module.scss";
   │         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   ╵
  styles/app.scss 14:9  root stylesheet
Import trace for requested module:
./styles/app.scss
./pages/_app.js
./styles/app.scss
```

But I imported that `SCSS` file in app.scss

My folder structure

[image]

My `app.js`

```
import "../styles/globals.scss";
import "../styles/app.scss";
```

My `app.scss`

```
@import "./abstracts/variables.scss";
@import "./abstracts/mixins.scss";

@import "./components/Header.module.scss";
@import "./components/Footer.module.scss";
@import "./pages/Home.module.scss";
@import "./pages/Haveproject.module.scss";
```

I tried to change without dot, but It did not work. Like this

```
@import "pages/Haveproject.module.scss";
```

I don't know what is my mistake. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a lowercase instead of an uppercase might be responsible for your error.

It should be `@import "./pages/HaveProject.module.scss"` instead of  `@import "./pages/Haveproject.module.scss"`

We have all been there, typos can be very frustrating.

Comment: Although not entirely, it was partially resolved. Because I have other names of pages and components like ```ServiceCard.module.scss``` or ```BlogPage.module.scss``` and the error returns only ```Haveproject```. I tried your advice and changed the name to ```Haveproject```. It did not work. But when I changed  ```Project```, It worked. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Hello i know why when you renamed it Projet it worked, i just had same issue and when i had a component named by mistake AnimationComponent and i renamed it animationComponent and it did same bug as you . if you dont change a letter but just a capital it doesnt work xD. it dont refresh on capital letters only if the word changed

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).